# Webservice has support multi-threading?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I built a web service. This web service need to cache a data. Data is a list of objects. Depend on passed parameters in web method, data will be filtered and returned to client.

```
public class UpdateService : WebService
{
   public List<object> Get(...)
   {
      return Util.Filter(CachingData.Data, ...);
   }
}
```

I need to cache this data, and it must be refreshed (renew) after each 1 hours. I build a static class named CachingData. In this class, I create a static Threading Timer:

```
public static class CachingData
{
    public static List<object> Data; // cached data

    private static System.Threading.Timer tmrGetHSXData = new System.Threading.Timer(DoGethsxEOD, null, 0, 60*60*1000);

    private static DoGethsxEOD()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

DoGethsxEOD is a static method which will be called after each 1 hour to refresh data. However, DoGethsxEOD only called one time. Threading is not working.

I want to cache data on this web service. After each 1 hour, this data will be refreshed. I use a Threading Timer for this task. However, it doesn't work.

I don't know webservice has a support using Threading. Please help me to solve this problem, and how to archive my purpose. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why don't you use the Classic Cache object and set an expiration (1 hour) daytime on it ?

you could create a wrapper around it to store the data you need into the cache and make it expired after 1 hour

```
Cache.Insert("CacheItem6", "Cached Item 6",
    null, DateTime.Now.AddHours(1), 
    System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
```

for more info :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/18c1wd61%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

if you want Cache.Insert allow you also to pass a Call-Back Delegate that you can use to automatically refresh your cache:

```
Cache.Insert("MyText", someTextVariable, null, DateTime.Now.AddHours(1), 
             TimeSpan.Zero, CacheItemPriority.High, 
             new CacheItemRemovedCallback(ItemRemoved))


public void ItemRemoved(string key, object value, CacheItemRemovedReason reason)
{
    // write your refresh logic
}
```

Comment: You can give me an example. If, Cache object expire, how to refresh it. Thanks.

Comment: when the cache expired the item will not longer exist into the cache and it will return null. At this point you can refresh the cache.
you could handle it on the your "Get logic"

Comment: Cache Data always new after each 1 hour. How to refresh it. Thanks.

Comment: instead of having a timer you can set the expiration date on the cache at 1h. If no one will call the webservice the cache will not be refreshed(you don't need refresh at this point as no one is calling the webservice). When the first request come in your logic will relized the cache is expired and will refresh it
I have edited my answer